# How to populate table with images from array list in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am in process of learning JavaFX, and I want to populate one table column with images of books and other with summary. Can I do that? When I tried I only succeeded to get one image for all books. Simple example

```
package tableviewexample;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;


public class Book  {
        public static  String path = "src/tableviewexample/Opis/";
        public static ArrayList<Book> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
    private boolean checked;
    private boolean isItAvailable;
    private String bookName;
    private String isbn;
    private String authorName;
    private int numberOfPages;
    private String summary;
    private String publisher;
    private String mainPage;
    private double cost;
    private int quantity;
    private String genre;
    private Image image;
    public Book() {

    }
    public Book(boolean checked, boolean isItAvailable, String bookName, String isbn, String authorName, int numberOfPages,
                  String summary, String publisher, String mainPage, double cost,
                  int quantity, String genre) {
        this.isItAvailable = isItAvailable;
        this.checked = checked;
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.authorName = authorName;
        this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.mainPage = mainPage;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.genre = genre;
    }
    public String getBookName() {
       return bookName.get();
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName.set(bookName);
    }
    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }
    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }
    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String getAuthorName() {
        return authorName;
    }

    public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
        this.authorName = authorName;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPages() {
        return numberOfPages;
    }

    public void setNumberOfPages(int numberOfPages) {
        this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }


    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }


    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }


    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }


    public String getMainPage() {
        return mainPage;
    }


    public void setMainPage(String mainPage) {
        this.mainPage = mainPage;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }


    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }


    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }   

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public boolean getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public boolean getIsItAvailable() {
        return isItAvailable;
    }

    public void setIsItAvailable(boolean isItAvailable) {
        this.isItAvailable = isItAvailable;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "AUTHOR: " + getAuthorName() + "\nPUBLISHER:" + getPublisher() +
                "\nNAME:" + getBookName() + "\nPRICE: " + getCost();
    }

    //helper function from file to string convertor
    public static String fromFileToString(File file)
    throws IOException {
      int len;
      char[] chr = new char[4096];
      final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
      final FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
      try {
          while ((len = reader.read(chr)) > 0) {
              buffer.append(chr, 0, len);
          }
      } finally {
          reader.close();
      }
      return buffer.toString();
    }
    public static void init() {
        ArrayList<String> txtSummary = new ArrayList<>();
        txtSummary.add("basara.txt");
        txtSummary.add("igraPrestola.txt");
        txtSummary.add("sudar_kraljeva.txt");
        txtSummary.add("oluja_maceva.txt");

        try {
        Book pBasara = new Book(false, true, "Fama o biciklistima", "978-86-521-1090-2", "Svetislav Basara",
        334," ","Dereta", "src/tableviewexample/Images/basara.jpg", 16.50, 20, "filozofsko - religijski roman, istorijska");
        pBasara.setSummary(Book.fromFileToString(new File(path + txtSummary.get(0))));

        Book pIgraPrestola = new Book(false, true, "Igra prestola", "978-86-743-6099-6", "Dzordz R.R. Martin",
        599,"","Laguna", "src/tableviewexample/Images/igraPrestola.jpg", 20 , 2, "epska fantastika, politicka strategija");
        pIgraPrestola.setSummary(Book.fromFileToString(new File(path + txtSummary.get(1))));

        Book pSudarKraljeva = new Book(false, true,"Sudar Kraljeva", "978-86-743-6140-5", "Dzordz R.R. Martin",
        672,"","Laguna", "src/tableviewexample/Images/sudar_kraljeva.jpg", 26.20 , 2, "epska fantastika, politicka strategija");
        pSudarKraljeva.setSummary(Book.fromFileToString(new File(path + txtSummary.get(2))));

        Book pOlujaMaceva = new Book(false, true, "Oluja maceva -deo prvi: Celik i sneg", "978-86-743-6185-6", "Dzordz R.R. Martin",
        384,"","Laguna", "src/tableviewexample/Images/oluja_maceva.jpg", 20.50 , 2, "epska fantastika, politicka strategija");
        pOlujaMaceva.setSummary(Book.fromFileToString(new File(path + txtSummary.get(3))));
        list.add(pBasara);
        list.add(pIgraPrestola);
        list.add(pSudarKraljeva);
        list.add(pOlujaMaceva);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }


        }
    }
```

And tableview example

```
package tableviewexample;

import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;


public class TableViewExample extends Application {

    Button catalogue;
    Button back;
    Stage stage;
    Scene sceneTable;
    Scene sceneFirst;
    GridPane pane;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        catalogue = new Button("Catalogue");
        Book.init();
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        stage = primaryStage;
        pane = new GridPane();
        sceneFirst = new Scene(pane,200, 200);
        pane.add(catalogue, 0, 0);
        catalogue.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                ObservableList<Book> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Book.list);
                TableView<Book> table = new TableView<Book>();
                table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
                TableColumn<Book, String> imageCol = new TableColumn<Book, String>();
                TableColumn<Book, String> descriptionCol = new TableColumn<Book, String>();
                Callback<TableColumn<Book, String>, TableCell<Book, String>> cellFactory;
                table.setItems(data);

                back = new Button("Back");
                AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
                sceneTable = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

                imageCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("mainPage"));
                descriptionCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("summary"));

                cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn<Book, String>, TableCell<Book, String>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell call(final TableColumn param) {
                                          final HBox box= new HBox();                         
                     ImageView imageview = new ImageView();                      
                     final TableCell cell = new TableCell() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            box.setSpacing(10) ;
                            box.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
                            Image img = null;
                            //if i put foor loop here, it wil set image of last book in list
//this is confusing part for me
// how to make to get exact image for every book
                               //this line is only for example, just to show something in table

                            Book book = Book.list.get(0);
                            img = new Image(new File(book.getMainPage()).toURI().toString());

                                imageview.setImage(img);
                                imageview.setFitHeight(320.0);
                                imageview.setFitWidth(200.0);
                                box.getChildren().add(imageview);    

                        } 
                    }
                    };
                cell.setGraphic(box);
                return cell;
                }
            };
            imageCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
                table.getColumns().addAll(imageCol, descriptionCol);
                AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(table, 30.0);
                AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(table, 10.0);
                AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(table, 10.0);
                AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(table, 10.0);
           //     refresh(table, data);
                root.getChildren().addAll(table, back);
                back.setOnAction(e -> ButtonClicked(e));
            stage.setScene(sceneTable);
            }   

            public void ButtonClicked(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == back) {
                    stage.setScene(sceneFirst);
                }

            }
        });    


        primaryStage.setScene(sceneFirst);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using raw types in the cell factory? You should have `public TableCell<Book, String> call(TableColumn<Book, Cell> param) {...}` and then fix all the types in your `updateItem` method accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure that I understand you :(

Comment: The call method in your cell factory is defined as `public TableCell call(TableColumn param)`. Why??? Why are you using `TableCell` (which is a raw type, and you should be getting a warning about it) instead of a properly typed parameter: `TableCell<Book, String>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you always get the first book in the list : `Book book = Book.list.get(0);`

Try changing that to:
`img = new Image(new File( item.toString() ) );`

Comment: Yes, yes, I just fixed it to get something. I tried Book book = (Book) item;
but that only throws 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to tableviewexample.Book

Comment: can you tell me what type item is in "updateItems" ? you can use item.getClass() to print.

Comment: It's String (output of item.getClass() : class java.lang.String ) I think that it is becouse I have mainPage atribute in Book class. It represents path to image of book front page

Comment: @svasa Since it's a `TableColumn<Book, String>`, the only possible type for `item` is obviously `String`.

Comment: @MGogic so item is a path to image of book front page?

Comment: Yes, item is a path to image

Comment: they whycan't you just use `img = new Image(new File( item.toString() ) );`

Answer (score 0):

To get the book from the current row in the `updateItem()` method, you can do

```
Book book = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
```

For this to work, you need to properly type everything, instead of using raw types (you know there is a reason your IDE is issuing all sorts of warnings, right?):

```
cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn<Book, String>, TableView<Book, String>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<Book, String> call(TableColumn<Book, String> param) {
        return new TableCell<Book, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    // if you really need the book, do:
                    Book book = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());

                    // but surely you just need 
                    imageview.setImage(new Image(item));
                    // ...
                    setGraphic(box);
                }
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Or, in a more up-to-date style:

```
cellFactory = tCol -> new TableCell<Book, String>() {
    @Overide
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            Book book = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
            // ...
            setGraphic(box);
        }

    }
}l
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stuck on this for two days :)